# FromUri attribute not working for string/object dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've got a web service controller that is trying to get a string/object dictionary. I thought that since it could implicitly convert the object in question (DateTime) to a string, I wouldn't have to use a [FromUri] attribute, but when I debuged it, it was null. So I throw a [FromUri] up there, and it has a dictionary, but it's empty. The uri looks like this:

```
http://localhost:2806/api/Controller/MethodName?@StartDate=11/1/14&@EndDate=12/1/14
```

Can anyone see an obvious problem? Please let me know if more context would help.

My controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage MethodName([FromUri]Dictionary<string, object> parametersDictionary)
    {
        try
        {
            var messages = DbBuisnessLogic.GetDataFromDb(parametersDictionary);
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messages);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, json);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new HttpError(e.Message));
        }
    }
```

Comment: - Why your query string has spaces ? - What do you use to encode your data into the Query string ? - if you can show us the web API controller that will help.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the spaces. I added the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work if your url looked like:

```
http://localhost/api/Controller/MethodName/?parametersDictionary[0].Key=StartDate&parametersDictionary[0].value=20141201T0003Z&parametersDictionary[1].Key=EndDate&parametersDictionary[1].Value=20141207T0003Z
```

You'll notice the date format being passed is different. that is because the slashes in your example Uri are not allowed (as slashes are used as part of a route).

I would also recommend changing your strategy of using a Dictionary read from the Uri altogether. Its a little ugly and if you're just taking in a certain amount of parameters (ie. just start and end date) then I'd define just a route that takes them in explicitly. It looks less bad in the Uri and the code is easier to deal with. I assume the example you gave is a simplified version of what you're trying to achieve but even then, if you know all possible values you want to take in, then define them. Example:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]DateTime startDate, [FromUri]DateTime endDate)
```

Then call

```
http://localhost/api/Controller/MethodName/?startDate=20141201T0003Z&endDate=20141207T0003Z
```

Comment: Awesome! Is there a name for the formatting that you put that date in?

Comment: I believe it is ISO 8601 http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003169674.htm

Comment: Yes, Thanks! Sorry, I got busy and forgot to mark it.